# Softlayer: Cannot create load balancer service group

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I cannot create a load balancer group through the API, CLI or Portal.

I have a key on a 'Super User': terraform-ms-dev

----Error when using API

> softlayer_lb_local_service_group.shares_http_lb_group: Error creating
>   load balancer service group: SoftLayer_Exception_Public: Errors
>   encountered when setting up the load balancer! Please contact customer
>   service. (HTTP 200)

----Error when using CLI

```
slcli loadbal group-add --allocation 50 --port 80 --routing-type 2 --routing-method 10 local:188345
```

> SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): Errors encountered when
>   setting up the load balancer! Please contact customer service.

I also get this error when logged in as 'ROOT' account (account owner): `IBM1078445`

----Error when using Portal

> Errors encountered when setting up the load balancer! Please contact
>   customer service.

Can someone look into why I cannot create load_balancer group ?

This ticket is open with softlayer here:
https://control.softlayer.com/support/tickets/36680965

Answer (score 0):

if you cannot create a load balancer using the Sofltayer's portal that is probably an issue with your account or with softlayer itself, i recomend you wait until the softlayer developers take a look to this issue.

Regards